# Is it possible to get data by value in Redis?

Tags: python, redis

I already checked to be able to find a row by key in Redis. But I wonder if it's possible to find a row by value in same row. For example, my row's data is {"1", "A", "B"} and I wanna find the row by "A" or "B" not by "1" (first columns is key in this case) with Python.

Comment: Huh? Redis doesn't have *"rows"*. It has strings, hashes, lists and sets AFAIK.

Comment: I see, then It might be impossible to get data by value. Is there any solution for getting data by value?

Comment: create value and key same.

Comment: I need to get data by index or by a specific value, so I need two way in order to getting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis has nothing out of the box for this. You can create a [secondary index](https://redis.io/topics/indexes) in Redis on the value. It comes at a cost though - you need more memory to store the index.

Answer (score 0):

you can build your own 'value index'.

for example, you can add a second key with type sorted set,  with key: A, value: 1(1), 2(2), 3(3), 4(4), the number in parentheses is score, you can use your own score like timestamp.

so when you want first ten primary key with value A, use this:

```
zrangebyscore A -inf +inf limit 0 10
```